# Fading in and out UIButton in view

Tags: ios, ipad, uibutton

In my iPad app I need to display cover-Images of publications. The user can tap on a cover to get details.

I thought about rendering UIButtons as custom buttons with the cover image as Background-image. Is it possible to fade UIButtons in and out? The user can choose a category of publications to be displayed, and ih he changes the category I wanted to fade some publications out.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `alpha` property of any `UIView` (which includes a `UIButton`) can be animated using the block-based animations method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{myButton.alpha = 0.0;}];
```

This will fade your button out over a 0.25 second period. Set the `alpha` to 1.0 to fade it back in again.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that! This means that I need to create a UIview for each Button and embed the UIButton inside the UIView then?

Comment: No, `myButton` is your button in this example. This is a class method of `UIView`, it does not need an instance to be called against.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the button to respond to events while it's animating, make sure to enable user interaction

```
[UIView
        animateWithDuration:5.0
        delay:0.0
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
        animations:^{ button.alpha = 0.0; }
        completion:nil];
```